# formatting a string from X to Y +

Tags: regex, perl, bash, awk, sed

**Not sure of the best way to do this but could I do this using any of bash/awk/sed/perl/...?**

**Brief Description**

I want to be able to take this

```
(Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change) + Intra TAU success Times(SGW change) + Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)+ Period TAU success Times(SGW change))/(Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change) + Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)+ Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)+ Period TAU request Times(SGW change)) x 100%
```

and format it to this

```
([Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU success Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW change)])/([Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW change)])*100
```

**Detailed Description**

I want to be able to take this format (this would be one line, jsut presented like this for clarity)

```
(
Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change) + 
Intra TAU success Times(SGW change) + 
Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)+ 
Period TAU success Times(SGW change)
)/(
Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change) + 
Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)+ 
Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)+ 
Period TAU request Times(SGW change)
) 
x 100%
```

and produce this format:

```
(
[Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+
[Intra TAU success Times(SGW change)]+
[Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+
[Period TAU success Times(SGW change)]
)/(
[Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+
[Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)]+
[Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+
[Period TAU request Times(SGW change)]
)
*100
```

what i want to do

1 add square brackets `[]` to all counters

take this string 
`Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)` 
and produce this 
`[Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)]`

**Note** Not all counter strings will end in a `)`

2 replace `x` with `*`

3 remove the `%`

Comment: If not all strings end with a `)` then what are the other possibilities?

Comment: One strategy to consider is to treat the input at its semantic meaning, parse it into a structure, and then output it in its new format, rather than treating it as malleable text.

Comment: @hwnd it could some thing like this `Period TAU request Times` as apposed to this `Period TAU request Times(SGW change)` so it could basically be [a-z]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this sed command also,

```
$ sed 's/ + /]+[/g;s/+ /]+[/g;s/(I/([I/g;s/))\//)])\//g;s/) x 100%/])*100/g' file
([Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU success Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW change)])/([Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW change)])*100
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/ + /]+[/g;         #   Replace all the ` + ` with `]+[`
s/+ /]+[/g;          #   FRom the above output it again replaces `+ ` with `]+[`
s/(I/([I/g;          # Again from the above result, it replaces `(I` with `([I`
s/))\//)])\//g;      # Again from the output of above, it replaces `))/` with `)])/`
s/) x 100%/])*100/g  # Again from the above output, it replaces `) x 100%` with `])*100`
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

`STRING="(Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change) + Intra TAU success Times(SGW change) + Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)+ Period TAU success Times(SGW change))/(Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change) + Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)+ Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)+ Period TAU request Times(SGW change)) x 100%"`

This works for your example:

```
echo $STRING | sed 's/Intra/[&/g; s/Period/[&/g; s/change)/&]/g; s/ x / * /g; s/\([0-9]*\)%/\1/g'
```

Assumptions:

- At the beginning of "Intra" or "Period" is where "[" needs to be added
- At the end of "changes)" is where "]" needs to be added
- " x " is between 2 spaces
- There is no space between a number and "%"

---

With regards to **`sed`**:

- `&` represents "entire match"
- `\(...\)` captures a group and `\1` spits out the first captured group 
  `\2` spits out the second ... so on and so forth

Comment: tks but the output has a space before and after the `+` sign

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl regex to enclose groups of letters, spaces, and balanced paranthesis in braces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

$data =~ s{\s*\bx\b\s*}{*}g;
$data =~ s{%}{}g;
$data =~ s{\s* ( (?:[a-z\s]+|\([a-z\s]+\))+ )(?<!\s) \s*}{[$1]}ixg;

print $data;

__DATA__
(
Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change) + 
Intra TAU success Times(SGW change) + 
Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)+ 
Period TAU success Times(SGW change)
)/(
Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change) + 
Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)+ 
Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)+ 
Period TAU request Times(SGW change)
) 
x 100%
```

Outputs:

```
([Intra TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU success Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU success Times(SGW change)])/([Intra TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Intra TAU request Times(SGW change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW not change)]+[Period TAU request Times(SGW change)])*100
```

Comment: how exactly would I go about testing this? could i use the perl in cygwin on windows? much appreciated

Comment: @HattrixNZ You don't have Perl available?

Comment: @DavidO i do have perl in cygwin or am i missing something?

Comment: @HattrixNZ That ought to do.

Comment: this does not get rid of the %, also adds a space before and after the *. tks tho!

Comment: @HattrickNZ It doesn't add a space, it leaves it there.  That shouldn't matter since you just added space to the question for readability, but adjusted regex to remove that anyway.  As for the percent sign, you could easily have added a regex yourself for that, but done so for you now as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that some of the other solutions aren't flexible enough to handle some of the input cases that you haven't told us about (and besides, I felt like playing with Marpa), so here's a more heavy-duty solution.

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dumper;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
  source => \(<<'EOGRAMMAR')
    :default ::= action => ::first
    lexeme default = latm => 1

    Expression ::= Division ('x') Percentage
                                   action => expression
    Division ::= Sum ('/') Sum     action => division
    Sum ::= ('(') Sum (')')                  
        | Variable ('+') Sum       action => sum
        | Variable                           

    Percentage ::= Number ('%')
    Variable ::= VariablePart+     action => variable
    VariablePart ::= Words         action => [value]
                 | '(' Words ')'   action => [values]

    Words ~ [A-Za-z ]+
    Number ~ [\d]+
    Whitespace ~ [\s]+
    :discard ~ Whitespace
EOGRAMMAR
});

my $recognizer = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({
  grammar => $grammar,
  semantics_package => 'action',
});

sub action::expression { "$_[1]*$_[2]" }

sub action::division { "($_[1])/($_[2])" }

sub action::sum { "$_[1]+$_[2]" }

sub action::variable {
  my @parts = @_;
  shift @parts;
  @parts = map @$_, @parts;
  s/^\s+// for @parts;
  s/\s+$// for @parts;
  return '[' . join('', @parts) . ']';
}

my $input = do { local $/; <> };
$recognizer->read(\$input);
my $output = $recognizer->value;
if ($output) {
  print $$output, "\n";
  exit 0;
} else {
  print STDERR "Parse failed";
  exit 1;
}
```

It uses a grammar to parse the kind of expression you showed, and the grammar actions, rather than building up a parse tree, simply reconstruct the output in the format that you asked for. It's relatively free about whitespace and what can occur in "variable names" in the input, although the grammar might have to be modified if there are expressions in a format I didn't capture.

Comment: tks but how do i get Marpa from cygwin on windows7? found this link but not too sure [link](http://marpa-guide.github.io/chapter1.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s*((Intra|Period)[^)]*\))\s*/[\1]/g;s/\s*x\s*/*/;s/%//' file
```

Surround strings beginning with `Intra` or `Period` to the following `)` with square brackets deleting any pre/post white space. Replace `x` with `*` deleting any pre/post white space. Finally delete `%`.